# packet forwarding using iptables and nfqueue

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, iptables

I have 3 machines - A, B, C and I am trying to do something similar to DNAT.

1) A sends a packet to B.

2) B receives the packet and modifies it to send it to C.

At machine-B, I am using the iptables and nfqueue to receive the packet.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

On machine-B, (1) I modify the packet (let's call modified packet as new_packet), (2) I send the new_packet to machine-C using raw sockets, and (3) drop the original packet machine-B received.

I feel these steps are redundant (which inflate latency), and there should be a better way of doing it.

Is it possible to  mangle the original packet received by machine-B, and then simply forward the packet to C.

P.S. The DNAT feature in iptables is not useful, as I need to do more modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I know that question was asked 7 monthes ago, but IMHO the fastest way to do any processing of packets is to write kernel-module. Handling all this stuff in user-space is very reduces the speed. And by the way there is no zero-copy in this situation, so once again - kernel-module is the best solution